# Run script on sleep event

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I've seen a lot of questions, etc. on how to wake from sleep, but nothing about how to run a script on a sleep event.

Can windows [Task Scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler) trigger a script when the PC is being put to sleep?

Comment: The following article might help. It describes a similar situation and talks about triggering on sleep/hibernation: https://superuser.com/questions/146520/is-there-any-way-to-execute-something-when-closing-the-laptops-lid

Comment: [solution on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/146520/is-there-any-way-to-execute-something-when-closing-the-laptops-lid)

Comment: May be something like this vbscript [Auto-Shutdown_On_Idle_TimeOut.vbs](https://pastebin.com/GwRsGbXR)